# How do I extract even elements of an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [4, 5, 7, 8, 14, 45, 76];

function even(a) {
  var ar = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    ar.push(a[2 * i + 1]);
  }

  return ar;
}

alert(even(arr));
```

http://jsbin.com/unocar/2/edit

I have tried this code in order to output even (index) elements of an array. It works, but it also outputs some empty elements. How do I fix this code to output only existing elements?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Either use modulus:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 === 0) { // index is even
        ar.push(a[i]);
    }
}
```

or skip every second element by incrementing `i` accordingly:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2) {  // take every second element
    ar.push(a[i]);
}
```

**Notice:** Your code actually takes the elements with *odd* indexes from the array. If this is what you want you have to use `i % 2 === 1` or start the loop with `var i = 1` respectively.

Comment: probably, i said it incorrectly. i meant ordinal number of elements- for instance- 5 is second, 8 is fourth.. and so on..

Comment: to start from the second element:
for(var i = 1;

Answer (score 20):

For IE9+ use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = [4,5,7,8,14,45,76];
var filtered = arr.filter(function(element, index, array) {
  return (index % 2 === 0);
});
```

With a fallback for older IEs, all the other browsers are OK without this fallback

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This will work on 2018 :)

take the odd indexes and apply to filter

```js
var arr = [4, 5, 7, 8, 14, 45, 76, 5];
let filtered = arr.filter((a,i) => i%2===1);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: even shorter: `arr.filter((a,i) => i%2)`

Answer (score 7):

Even if this question is quite old, I would like to add a one-liner filter:
Odd numbers: `arr.filter((e,i)=>i%2)`
Even numbers: `arr.filter((e,i)=>i%2-1)`
A more 'legal' way for even numbers: `arr.filter((e,i)=>!(i%2))`

There's no need to check with `===1` like sumit said. `mod 2` already returns a 0 or a 1, you can let them be interpreted as boolean values.

You can use `i&1` instead of `i%2`, while it benefits performance on big arrays, it can work only on 31 bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you try with the % operator. It gives  you the remaining of a division.

replace the loop block with

```
if ((i % 2) === 0) {
    ar.push(a[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [4,5,7,8,14,45,76];

function even(a)
{
  var ar = [];  

  for (x in a)
  {

    if((a[x]%2)==0)
    ar.push(a[x]);  

  }
return ar;
}

alert(even(arr));
```

Comment: It is discouraged to iterate over an array using `for...in`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @Felix Kling : sorry.. i was unaware of that.. :) thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to explain why your result is not what you expected since everyone else shows excellent solutions. You are iterating over an array size N so your resulting array will attempt to push elements in an array that will result in size N.  Since only N/2 will be found in the original array your resulting array will fill the rest with blanks to fill in the rest of N.  So if you checked to see if a[2*i] exists OR checked to see if a[i] % 2 == 0 before inserting, your resulting array will contain only the even indexed values