# Trying to create a for loop to log even numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So im trying to create a loop to log the even numbers produced in my array, i have this but i cant seem to figure out where im stuck, sorry for the basic question still learning.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray % 2 === 0)
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `myArray[i] % 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract even elements of an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243355/how-do-i-extract-even-elements-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the `[i]` in the if clause:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] % 2 === 0)
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Jayyy It should. It works in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kyudt1kj/

Comment: noob mistake, had the output open instead of my console, sorry thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting array value correctly. Use index to access array value as myArray[i]

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] % 2 === 0)
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You forgot myArray`[i]` inside if.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] % 2 === 0)
    console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Try to Run code snippet and click inspect element and retry to go on Console . For me i see it's working .

Answer (score 0):

As many have already answered, you forgot the index of your array.

To improve your code, instead of a for loop you could filter your array:

```
const result = myArray.filter(i => i % 2 === 0)
console.log(result)
```

or if you wanted to log it on every iteration:

```
myArray.filter(i => {if(i % 2 === 0) console.log(i)})
```